# Understanding what happens to variables when passing functions as JavaScript variables

Tags: javascript

OK.  I am trying to understand closure in JavaScript.
I have a function but I am seeing inconsistent results.  When passing the url parameter it's fine unless it's being done in a callback.  I thought closure would retain that value in the function.

```
ABC.print = function (reportId, format, reportTitle) {
        alert("Coming in=" + format);  // Always has right value.

        var url = 'Main/MyModule/Print?reportId=' + reportId;
        url += '&format=' + format;
        url += '&reportTitle=' + reportTitle;   

        function printWindow(urlString) {
           window.open(urlString, 'Print', "toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=no");
        };    

        // What is the difference between?
   if (someCondition)
   {
      // Variables in url are not current, they retain first time value only.
      SomeFunction("Text", "Text 2", function () { printWindow(url); });
   }
   else {
      // Variables are always current
      printWindow();
   }
};
```

Comment: [You rather check this](https://www.google.com.bd/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20scope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that somewhere in your commented out part:

```
// Actually some logic but to simplify...
```

The value of of your variable `url` is changed.

When the function `printWindow()` is called, it will take the value of `url` *at that time the call is made* (and not the value of `url` at the time the function was defined.

The topic of **scope** may mess things up: your `var url=...` only exists inside the function `ABC.print`. As long as program execution is inside `ABC.print`, the var will have predictable results. But as soon as you pass the function `printWindow()` as a callback to somewhere else, you are no longer inside the ABC.print scope. So `url` value is undefined, or at best unstable/ unpredictable.

To solve this, you could give the variable `url` global scope: define it somewhere outside any function, so that it is available everywhere.

```
// global scope
var url;

ABC.print = function (reportId, format, reportTitle) {
  alert("Coming in=" + format);

  // give the global variable content here
  url = 'Main/MediaReach/Print?reportId=' + reportId;
  url += '&format=' + format;
  url += '&reportTitle=' + reportTitle;   

  printWindow = function () {
    alert("ulr = " + url);
    window.open(url, 'Print', "toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=no");
  };

  // Actually some logic but to simplify...
  printWindow();

  // passing printWindow as callback
  doSomething('myParam',printWindow);
};
```

Comment: Actually the logic checks a count and either calls printWindow() or calls a JqueryUI dialog with printWindow() as a callback.  I am not manipulating the url anywhere else.

Comment: I heard what you are saying, but I'm still trying to understand what you are saying.  If I get rid of PrintWindow and just pass the window.open(...) then it has the correct url.  However it then messes with my callback.

Comment: Yes making the url value global did it.  However I'm not sure why I had to make it global since the correct value was being passed into the main function.

Comment: Even though you may have passed it into main function, the value may no longer be there when PrintWindow is called later on. Putting url in global ensures that value is remembered as long as JavaScript is active.

Comment: Thank you for your help.